# Crash in AutofillManager NPE: trying to invoke virtual method containsKey(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, android-autofill-manager

I have no direct traces of using AutofillManager in my project but still getting this crash in crash analytics. How we can handle this?

Crash Logs-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.containsKey(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference.

    android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.onAuthenticationResult AutofillManager.java:1798
    android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult Activity.java:8674
    android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults ActivityThread.java:5850
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult ActivityThread.java:5896
    android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute ActivityResultItem.java:54
    android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute ActivityTransactionItem.java:45
    android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks TransactionExecutor.java:135
    android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute TransactionExecutor.java:95
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage ActivityThread.java:2434
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage Handler.java:106
    android.os.Looper.loopOnce Looper.java:226
    android.os.Looper.loop Looper.java:313
    android.app.ActivityThread.main ActivityThread.java:8633
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Method.java
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run RuntimeInit.java:567
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main ZygoteInit.java:1135
```

Answer (score 4):

It is happening only for Android 12 devices.

Here is the [open issue by Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228529893).

Answer (score 1):

There is an [open issue in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1280378) for something similar to this. It looks like it might have been fixed in the latest version, so we'll probably have to wait for users to update their browsers and webviews.